# Java AWT Unable to change a value of a variable in the actionPerformed() function

Tags: java, awt

I have two buttons on an applet and a variable "stat". The idea is that I want to change a value of the variable by either pressing button plus or minus that will add or subtract 1, respectively. But the variable "stat" does not change its value in any way. Can you please help me understand in what way can I overwrite a value of the variable?

```
import  java.awt.*;
import  java.applet.*;
import  java.awt.event.*;

public  class  test  extends  Applet implements ActionListener
{ 

   int stat=0;
   Button plus, minus;
   String str="";
   
   public void init()
   {
       
       plus = new Button("+");
       plus.setActionCommand("+");
       
       minus = new Button("-");
       minus.setActionCommand("-");
       

       minus.addActionListener(this);
       plus.addActionListener(this);
           
       add(plus);
       add(minus);
           
   }
   
   
 
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
        str = ae.getActionCommand();

        if (str.equals("minus")) { stat-=1;  }
        else if (str.equals("plus")) { stat+=1; }
        
   }
   
   
}
```

Comment: How is `str.equals("minus")` to ever be true if the action command is `"-"`? Same thing for `"plus"` and `"+"`.

Comment: I guess I'm blind. Thank you!

Comment: Probably a matter of reading out the code in your mind which turns `"+"` into `"plus"` :D

Comment: BTW, if the action command is not already set, it will default to the the label of the button when `getActionCommand` is invoked.  In your case above, it does not need to be explicitly set.